# BorderLayout Left Assignment

Tags: java, jbutton, border-layout

I have a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` and some Buttons on SOUTH.
When I add the Buttons they are in the middle. But I want them to be on the left.

Is that possible?

Comment: On the left of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html

Each region may contain no more than one component, and is identified by a corresponding constant: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, and CENTER.

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
p.add(new Button("Okay"), BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Create a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`, add this panel to SOUTH position of the main panel. Create another `JPanel`, add your buttons to this panel (using what ever layout manager you need. Now add the "button" panel to the south panel at the WEST position

Comment: Hey no problem,  I use borderlayout for everything! It's an excellent layout.